# How to disable submit button if (http), (https), or (www) are found in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea

I already have a code I created in javascript that disables the submit button on a form if a dropdown choice is chosen but I also want to turn off the submit button if the string (http), (https), or (www) is typed into textarea of the form. Any help in the right direction would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<textarea id="my-textarea"></textarea>

document.querySelector('#my-textarea').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    if (event.target.value.includes('http') || event.target.value.includes('https') || event.target.value.includes('www')) {
    console.log('invalid');
  } else {
    console.log('valid');
  }
});
```

Here is the sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2qorhekd

Comment: thank you for your response but this isn't working at all, was going to try to get it to work with my setup and then change it from there but its not working on the jsfiddle. Maybe im missing something.

Comment: Hello, you could try again the edited fiddlejs, thank you.

Comment: I forgot to add the 'event' object in the arrow function, but it's working now. just make sure to copy the updated answer / code. thank you.

Comment: You rock, once I edited it to stop the button from being disabled its working now 100%. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to help bro. Thank you. :D

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for the `keyup` event and check the input when the event fires.

Something like:

```js
let illegalWords = ["http", "https", "www"];

function checkText(text) {
  if (text.length >= 1) {
    for (let word of illegalWords) {
      if (text == word) {
        // word found, remove submit button
        console.log("found");
        document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea onkeyup='checkText(this.value);'></textarea>
<button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

You could add an `else` block to this code to make the submit button appear (if not currently visible) when the illegal words are removed.

Comment: Thank you for this response, it looked like it was promising and works inside the "Run code snippet" but once implemented into my page it doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens at all

Answer (score 0):

Function to test if string has contains http, https or www

```
var valid = function(text){
  var regex = /(https?|www)/;
  return !regex.test(text);
}
```

Comment: Wasn't sure how to implement this without context at first but once I got it I saw it wouldn't work for what I needed. Thank you for your submission though.